# How can I withdraw my ICE token balance from Metamask?

Tags: tokens, metamask

I have transferred my ICE tokens from myetherwallet to Metamask , It does show my balance in metamask but I am unable to send them ??

I do not get any option to send them..

Please help me find out a way to transfer this ICE to any trading platform.

Answer (score 2):

You can send it by opening metamask, selecting the "token" tab, clicking the "+"-button, entering:

Address: https://etherscan.io/address/0x5a84969bb663fb64f6d015dcf9f622aedc796750

Symbol: ICE

Decimals: 18

Then you should be able to see and send ICE in metamask. make sure you have the newest version of Metmask